# Simple question about inducing errors for os.Setenv() and os.Unsetenv()

Tags: go

I'm trying to figure out how too make os.Setenv() and os.Unsetenv() fail so I can write a _test.go around some code which calls these.   I want to be complete and test the failure conditions.

Of course, the signatures are: `func Setenv(key, value string) error` and `func Unsetenv(key) error`

I looked thru the source code and they had tests, but it doesn't look like they had a test where these failed.

Yeah, I could just ignore the error return, but that kinda defeats having an error return.
So, anyone have a lead to how to make these fail?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I will give that a try

Answer (score 1):

[`os.Setenv`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.1:src/os/env.go;l=119) is a very thin wrapper around [`syscall.Setenv`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.1:src/syscall/env_unix.go;drc=refs%2Ftags%2Fgo1.17.1;l=97), and simply returns whichever error `syscall.Setenv` returns, wrapped with `NewSyscallError`.

The error cases are evident in the source, which is only 18 lines long:

```
func Setenv(key, value string) error {
    envOnce.Do(copyenv)
    if len(key) == 0 {
        return EINVAL
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(key); i++ {
        if key[i] == '=' || key[i] == 0 {
            return EINVAL
        }
    }
    // On Plan 9, null is used as a separator, eg in $path.
    if runtime.GOOS != "plan9" {
        for i := 0; i < len(value); i++ {
            if value[i] == 0 {
                return EINVAL
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So to provoke an error, you need to satisfy any of the following:

- `len(key) == 0`
- `key[i] == '=' || key[i] == 0`
- `runtime.GOOS != "plan9"` and `value[i] == 0`

[`syscall.Unsetenv`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.1:src/syscall/env_unix.go;drc=refs%2Ftags%2Fgo1.17.1;l=61) on the other hand never returns an error, it can only return `nil`.

```
func Unsetenv(key string) error {
    envOnce.Do(copyenv)

    envLock.Lock()
    defer envLock.Unlock()

    if i, ok := env[key]; ok {
        envs[i] = ""
        delete(env, key)
    }
    unsetenv_c(key)
    return nil
}
```

I would speculate that it is written as returning an error for consistency with the `Setenv`, and to provide support for some future platform or environment where it may produce an error under certain conditions.

Comment: Thanks.    That helps.   I would have rather had os.Unsetenv() return nothing.  But just to return a value for no reason other than "consistency" seems wrong to me.